# php rearrange arrays together by keys position in every array

Tags: php, arrays

I have three arrays:

```
['a', 'apple', 'albania'];
['b', 'banana', 'brasil'];
['c', 'carrot', 'croatioa'];
```

I want to convert those three arrays to:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'];
['apple', 'banana', 'carrot'];
['albania', 'brasil', 'croatioa'];
```

How can I do it? 
I want the values with key `0` to form a new array and so on with all the keys

Any suggestion will be received.

Thank you!

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: Of course, I know that. I just need a direction.

Comment: 1) You could create a big array, loop over the inner arrays and create new array for each key (0, 1, 2). 2) Create 3 arrays loop over the old arrays and move each key (0, 1, 2) with it value to the corresponding new array.

Comment: I was trying to avoid using loops. isn't there a function that do this?

Comment: @DavSev - this isn't a common requirement, and so I cannot think of an inbuilt PHP function that will do this. I'd start with Tom Udding's suggestion and see how you go. Come back if you need more help.

Comment: @DavSev - you can actually do this with minimal code using `array_reduce` and `foreach`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `array_map()` that will return one array that consists of three arrays

```
$arr1 = ['a', 'apple', 'albania'];
$arr2 = ['b', 'banana', 'brasil'];
$arr3 = ['c', 'carrot', 'croatioa'];

$newArr = array_map(function($a, $b, $c){
    return [$a,$b,$c];
},$arr1, $arr2, $arr3);

print_r($newArr);
```

Comment: if you loop the `$newArr`, you will get the requested output.

Comment: Perhaps out of scope of the original request, but might this cause erroneous output if the source arrays are not equal in length? Just something to be mindful of. But excellent solution.

Comment: it is still okay if you have different array length

Comment: I thought you'd get `null` values when a value didn't exist in a shorter array.